# MySql - Read only on slave

Tags: mysql, replication

I want to make my MySql slave read only, i've been looking and found the [read_only](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_only) option, but its says that users with super privalges can still write (if i understand the text correctly), here is the grants for my app:

```
GRANT RELOAD, PROCESS ON *.* TO 'my_app'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `my_app`.* TO 'my_app'@'%'
```

will the app be able to write to the slave?

Comment: MySQL5.7 now has [`super_read_only`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_super_read_only)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the grants you just mentioned

```
GRANT RELOAD, PROCESS ON *.* TO 'my_app'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `my_app`.* TO 'my_app'@'%'
```

Based on this, ***you should not be able to write to the Slave*** because [SUPER is a system level privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) (**SUPER only appears in mysql.user as Super_priv**) and not a DB level privilege (**SUPER does not appear in mysql.db**). The first GRANT lacks SUPER privilege. The second GRANT does not have a SUPER privilege context at all.

Having SUPER privilege has a lot of firepower because you can run the following

- CHANGE MASTER TO
- KILL
- SET GLOBAL
- PURGE BINARY LOGS

Not every user needs this. Giving the SUPER privilege to just anyone can actually hamper a DBA from logging into mysql if max_connections is reached.

Answer (score 2):

Arbitrary or unintended updates to a slave may break replication or cause a slave to be inconsistent with respect to its master. Making a slave read_only can be useful to ensure that a slave accepts updates only from its master server and not from clients; it minimizes the possibility of unintended updates.
Set `read_only=1` in your `my.cnf/my.ini` file to ensure that a slave accepts updates only from its master server and restart your server.

Also I think you should avoid giving unnecessary `SUPER` privilege to other MySQL users for safety.

Comment: and will my app, who have `ALL` privileges be able to write to the slave?

Comment: Yes .. it will write on SLAVE because it has SUPER privilege, You should try to avoid using SUPER privilege for MySQL user which is used in your app.
Actually it's not recommended to allow write on SLAVE databases which can conflict with MASTER data and hence break in replication process.

Comment: No. All privileges is not super. Super is only granted explicitly or when you say with grant option. The permissions specified above will not be able to write to a read only db.